# How to evaluate String as expression to perform arithmetic operations on String in Rust, so that when user type 3 + 1 on console it gives 4

Tags: string, rust, calculator, arithmetic-expressions

I was trying to make a calculator in the Rust programming language. The calculator performs basic arithmetic operations like add, sutract, exponent etc. The challenging part for me is that the user input is a `String` and I want the calculator to be intelligent enough so that when the user types 3 + 1 on console it will return 4 or 2^3 = 8. I can parse the `String` into an integer or any other data type, but how can I convert "+" into the arithmetic operator?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This doesn't (I don't think) directly answer your question, but you may want to look at the [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) for parsing arithmetic expressions like `3 + 1`.

Comment: thanks that really helped to make a logic for the problem.

Answer (score 4):

you can use a crate named meval and just pass the string to the `eval_str` function

```
use meval::eval_str;

fn main() {
    let r = meval::eval_str("1 + 2").unwrap();
    println!("1 + 2 = {}", r);
}
```